# How do i open a file in my hard drive using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

I'm trying to make VB.Net open a video file when i type in the name for the film. This is what i have come up with so far:

```
Console.WriteLine("What film would you like to watch? ")
                filmtv = Console.ReadLine()
                Process.Start("G:\", filmtv)
```

This opens up the folder but doesn't open the file and begin playing. I'm still kind of a newbie so sorry if its a easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your nearly there, Ola's answer will work fine for Windows Media Player. If you want to open the file with the default program you have set to open video files rather than Windows Media Player try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("What film would you like to watch? ")
filmtv = Console.ReadLine()
Process.Start("G:\" & filmtv)
```

In VB.NET & and + are used to join strings together.

Comment: I tried this method and it didn't seem to work, it couldn't find the file it was looking for. Anyway around it?

Comment: did you mistype the filename?

Comment: Make sure you are including the file extension also. For example if you movie file is called 'skyfall.avi', when it asks what film you would like to watch you enter skyfall.avi. Alternatively you could add the file extension on in the code. If all the movies are in .avi format try this:  filmtv = console.ReadLine() & ".avi". You could take this further by checking if the input contains an extension, if it doesn't add the extension on.

Comment: I did add the file type at the end, i'll see if i can fix it, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in two arguments to the Start method, player exe and file name. Ex,

`Process.Start("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe", "name of file to play")`

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx